# Android Theme Style find and read correct attribute programmatically

Tags: android, attributes, styles, themes

I'm sure there is somewhere an correct answer to what I need, but i can't find it :(

I need to read programmatically attributes from style from theme... Here some simple code to make it more understandable.

```
//Custom attributes
    <declare-styleable name="Style_lib">
        <attr name="layoutElementStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="customTheme" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="customAttribute" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

// Theme / style
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="customTheme">@style/CustomTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomTheme" >
        <item name="layoutElementStyle">@style/StyleElement_CustomTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="StyleElement_CustomTheme" >
        <item name="customAttribute">@color/Red</item>
    </style>

// Layout
<FrameLayout 
...
    android:theme="?attr/customTheme">

<CustomElementView
        ...
        style="?attr/layoutElementStyle" />
...

//// Here everything works as expected, I don't have any probleme to apply theme or style, my problem is i need to get style="?attr/layoutElementStyle" programmatically in my custom view.

/// CustomView
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes){

int style = attrs.getStyleAttribute();

And now ??? how can I get my attribute from the style provided by my theme ?  style is the same value of R.attr.layoutElementStyle. But how can I obtain customAttribute inside StyleElement_CustomTheme provided by CustomTheme apply in customTheme of AppTheme...

}
```

I know how to do read a custom attribute when there is no style or theme. So please, understand my question is well how to read custom attributes from custom style provided by theme :) This exmaple has been shrink. Of course just to read on color, it makes no sens :).

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
int idStyle = getResources().getIdentifier("CustomTheme", "style", getPackageName());
```

Comment: This works, but it is hard coded. The only information I have is this Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes. defStyleAttr ad desStyleRes are null. So I can get style attribute id with attrs. But What should I do to retrieve the attribute contains in this style  ?

Comment: I tried this context.obtainStyledAttributes(style, ATTR_INDEX) but my attribute are not here. the value of style are good and I now my theme is apply because if I add android;background, I can see the preview use it. But I can find my custom attrbute inside the style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just succeed to do it.

```
when you obtain the value of your style attribute, it give you in this case the value of ?attr/layoutElementStyle. But since this is itself a style, the correct way to do it is:


int style = attrs.getStyleAttribute();
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(style, R.styleable.Style_lib);
int elementStyleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Style_lib_layoutElementStyle, -1);
a.recycle();

and then just do it as usual way;
 context.obtainStyledAttributes(elementStyleId , R.stylable.CustomView);
and so.
```

So with the style attribute, you just need to first retrieve the current style and then access to the attribute.

If someone as another kind of experience, I appreciate some feeback about that.

Thanks.